# Bitcoin mining algorithm - target - Java

Tags: mining-theory, bitcoinj, mining-software, mining-technical-details, algorithms

Default share difficulty is 1 (big-endian target for difficulty 1 is 0x00000000ffff0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)

**How to calculate this?

How it look like on Java code?

What algorithm of calculate this value?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty is a part of the block header called "bits". It is the 72nd to 75th bytes of the block header and looks like this in hex:

bits = 0x76270618

Remember this is little-endian! Actual big-endian version is 0x18062776
Take the first byte as the “exponent” and the other three bytes as the “coefficient”

Exponent = 0x18 = 24

Coefficient = 0x062776

Plug into this formula:

Coefficient * 2**(8*(Exponent - 3)) =
0x0000000000000000062776000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

And that's how you can calculate difficulty from bits.